# Call two cron expressions in one cron job

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

I am working on a task where I need to trigger a cronjob immediately after one cronjob is completed. Is there any way I can call the 2nd cronjob into 1st one, so that once the first one gets executed, the 2nd one should start automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, SAP Commerce Cloud offers this OOTB(Out Of The Box).

This can be achieved via composite cronjob:

```
INSERT_UPDATE CompositeCronJob; code[unique = true]      ; job(code)[default = 'compositeJobPerformable']; sessionLanguage(isocode)[default = 'en']
                          ; compositeJob ;

INSERT_UPDATE CompositeEntry; code[unique = true];     executableCronJob(code); compositeCronJob(code)[default = compositeJob];
                            ; cronJob1Entry      ; cronJob1                   ;
                            ; cronJob2Entry      ; cronJob2                  ;

# Adding trigger on the composite job . This will decide when the first cronjob from the sequence will start.
# After the first cronjob is finished the second will start
INSERT_UPDATE Trigger; cronjob(code)[unique = true]; cronExpression ;
                 ; compositeJob     ; 0 0/30 * ? * * * ;
```

You can find out more about Composite Jobs if you do a little digging. ex:
https://answers.sap.com/questions/12768289/how-to-create-composite-cronjob.html

Answer (score 0):

Check `CronJobService`

get the cronJobModel :
`cronJobService.getCronjob(code)`

execute the cronJob :
`cronjobService.performCronJob(cronJobModel)`